# Powershell sort hashtable based on count

Tags: sorting, powershell

I have code that takes array `$iis_stats` and displays (1) the content `NAME` (2) number of occurrences for this content `Value`

```
$iis_stats | group | % { $h = @{} } { $h[$_.Name] = $_.Count } {$h}
```

How do I sort $h by value in descending order and print it?

I tried

```
$h | sort-object @{Expression={$_[1]}; Ascending=$false} {$h}
```

And I get error:

```
Sort-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$h'.
At D:\Script\parse_IIS_logs.ps1:45 char:6
+ $h | sort-object @{Expression={$_[1]}; Ascending=$false} {$h}
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Sort-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SortObjectCommand
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
$h.getenumerator() | sort value -descending
```